# express rational number as sum of squares of unit fraction

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Let $q$ be a rational number with $0\lt q\leq\dfrac{\pi^2}6-1$. Then show that there exists a set $S\subset \{2,3,4,\dotsc\}$, such that

$$q=\sum_{n\in S}\frac1{n^2}$$

I have no clue about it. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

p.s.  I  encountered it when surfing the Internet. I only know the problem was from a math student who got perfect score on the IMO

Comment: What is $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$?

Comment: @ziang chen Even though you are not that new...Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.Also, many find the use of imperative ("Show") to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: @MatthewConroy    I  encountered it when surfing on the Internet. I only know  the problem was from a math "powerful" person

Comment: You seem to posting a large number of unmotivated questions with no evidence of any efforts of your own to solve them, and most phrased as imperatives ("show", "prove", etc.). Are you just copying all the problems you have found in a book, or do you actually have any interest in the solutions that people are posting

Comment: @ziangchen So, have you tried anything? Have you thought about it?  Where did you find it?

Comment: @MatthewConroy  from a math "powerful" person

Comment: @ziangchen I don't know what that means.

Comment: very late to the party, but just wanted to say that op was probably being honest about the source, since I also first saw this question posed presumably by the same person. unfortunately i do not recall his proof, since it was much simpler than the one in the paper by erdos (it was also for the harder finite version). i can ask him to see if he still remembers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem if i am not mistaken was proposed by P. Erdos and proved by R.L. Graham (and maybe Sierpsinski ) [in this article](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/64_07_reciprocals.pdf)

You can find much more than you want there.
I hope that this helps.

Comment: Very true (+1), although the result by Graham seems to cover finite sums of this type, whereas the OP here does not specify finite, so there might be a simpler proof in this case.

Comment: I suppose that the "powerfull" mathematician that ziang chen is referring to is simply P. Erdos

Comment: Yes, I have a suspicion that (s)he is going through some publication about Erdős and posting all the questions here for us to solve. Certainly does not seem to display much interest in any of the answers posted.

Comment: @OldJohn yes i have just read  another question which seems "Erdosian"

Comment: @panoramix  Actually, I know the problem from a math talent student who got  perfect score at IMO

Comment: @ziangchen so,challenge him or her to prove it!

Comment: @panoramix Thank you very much! I will read the paper carefully

Comment: @ziangchen you are welcome my friend